# excel conditional formatting help

Tags: excel

I have formatted the columns as follows:

> _($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??*);*(@_).

If I copy paste the value then it doesn't work.
But if I type 1234, then it automatically converts to $ 1,234.

But how can I make it work even I do pasting.

I googled it and found that conditional formatting is used in these scenario.(Am I right?)

I tried doing conditional formatting also but could not secceed.

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this in conditional formatting:

1. How to convert text so that final value will be like $ 1,234 ?
2. If the column is empty or white space , replace it with - in the center.

Any type of help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you pasting the information from? Chances are if you're pasting from another cell the clipboard is carrying the previous formatting in to the new cell and overwriting what you have. (This is along the lines of copy/pasting a cell with a border).

Comment: its coming from the linked server... which dumps the values from resultset.

Answer (score 3):

When you paste something into a cell in Excel, by default, the format is also pasted.  To prevent this, you must do a Paste Special, then choose to only paste the Value.

For the conditional formatting of the currency, you can set up a rule that looks like this:

[image]

Getting a '-' to appear in a blank cell is not possible in Excel formatting rules.  A dash can be inserted as formatting, but only as long as there is actual data in the cell.  If the cell is blank, Excel will not display any characters.

Comment: its coming from teh database.

Comment: The values from the database will overwrite any formatting you might have in the cells.  You will need to apply formatting after the data has been placed in the cells.

Comment: How do I be able to do that...could you explain lil' bit plz.

Comment: To apply the formatting after the insert/database_copy/etc you can write a short macro to loop through each of the cells.  If it's a number, apply the proper formatting.  If it's blank, replace the cell contents with a "-".

Answer (score 0):

If what appear to be numbers are imported as text there is likely to be a warning of this in Excel (a small green triangle in the top left of the cells - for all recent Excel versions can be turn on/off in Options, Formulas, Error Checking). By selecting a range that includes the first instance, these strings can be converted to General format (so that values are recognised as numbers) by clicking the warning icon and Convert to Number.

Then 'standard formatting' can be applied, perhaps:

```
` $* #,##0 ;($* #,##0)`
```

and empty cells selected with HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Go To Special..., Blanks then formatted Alignment Center and contents entered with Find (nothing) and filled with hyphens with Replace with `-`.